# How to send all the content of a S3 bucket into a Kinesis Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm looking for a way to play an entire S3 bucket into Kinesis Stream.

I know that I can connect my S3 bucket with a lambda, that can send messages to Kinesis, but it works only for updates in the bucket.

To be more specific, I send messages into a Kinesis Stream, that are listen by a lambda. From this Kinesis stream, I also send all messages into S3 with kinesis firehose (and [this lambda](https://github.com/awslabs/lambda-streams-to-firehose)) to archive them. And sometimes, I want to replay all my archived messages that are in S3. So the best way would be to send them from the S3 bucket in an other Kinesis Stream, that would be listen by the first lambda.